# Why angular Js and What is mean by Single Page Applications

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone please explain me why we need to go with Angular JS and what is meant by Single Page Applications.
Please give me a explained answer I am new to this Angular JS I never worked on this before.
I have interest to learn Angular JS please help me with this.
Instead of giving link please share your thought so that it will improve my understanding better than reading articles.

Comment: How about learning the basics and asking detail questions?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: try google, trust me you are not the first or last person asking this.

Comment: Opinion-based questions doesn't belong here. I'd also recommend you to have a look at the basics either at [egghead](http://egghead.io) or other resources. Also you can look up the phrase _Single Page Application_ (SPA) in a second. Also you can ask these questions on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the entire website and all its views(what you normally would call pages) are technically one html page that you write. So you have one index.html and it is your entire site, and it changes pages(technically it changes views, it is still the same page). What is happening on the lower levels is that javascript is generating your entire views, and so it is not like in regular sites where you just write html and that html appears. In angular you write html, but it is not those pages that appear, it's javascript that takes the html from those pages and throws them inside your main html page(the one page)

Explain to me who told you that you NEED to go with angular js? Like all things, single page applications in general and angular js specifically has its pros and cons. For mobile web apps angular js is my way to go because it offers 2 way data binding, really simplifies things like requests to the server etc...

But for websites, I wouldn't use it, search engines have problems crawling an angular js site because you need to be able to execute javascript to see anything. Also if people have javascript turned off, the entire angular js website is likely to fail and not load at all(unless you bother with some workarounds). These problems do not exist in regular web programming where you do regular html pages...